# How to fix "PAM: User account has expired" error?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

For security reasons I have disabled root user with the command `usermod --expiredate 1 root`. Of course, I had added myself to `wheel` group. I had no issues till today when I executed `sudo usermod --groups audio {user}` command with the following output

```
Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator
usermod: PAM: User account has expired
```

I thought all root privileges still be available via `sudo` but it seems I was wrong. I cannot change expire date for root user back - I have the same output. Any idea how to handle this without reinstalling the whole OS? Is there a file which I can edit manually using `vim`, for instance (since I am still able to use `sudo` command for such purpose)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can edit `/etc/shadow`, see [man 5 shadow](https://manpages.debian.org/shadow.5.en.html) for details on the format.

```
root::::::::
```

If you want to prevent root from logging in with a password, set the encrypted password field to blank or something invalid (typically `*` or `!`). Do make sure to remove the expiration date.

Comment: It works, thank you. I knew about `passwd --lock` but as `man` says it does not totally disable the account and "the user may still be able to login using another authentication token (e.g. an SSH key)." I thought the command I have chosen is better.

Answer (score 0):

Login as root and run the below command:

```
chage -E 2024-12-31 username
```

**Note**: Add an next date on present date.